# How to remove Nikon strap rings with plastic covers?

Tags: nikon, camera-straps

I want to remove the strap rings on my Nikon D7000. They look to be pretty standard triangular split rings, but they also have a little plastic cover on them. How do I safely remove the cover in such a way that I can put the ring and the cover back on later if so desired? After some examination, it looks like I could just pry it off, but it would be nice to know if anybody's has experience with this before, so I don't screw it up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here are some interesting on how other have done it. http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/933078/0&year=2010#8810526

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this on my D800, I assume they are exactly the same.

So first remove the plastic clips, just push them HARD towards the on-camera mounting post, they should just pop off.

Then remove the triangular rings, they are VERY stuff so you may need a flat-head screwdriver to pry the end open, just rotate them around like a key-ring and off they come.

I NEVER use a strap, and these are very annoying jiggling about all the time...

Comment: I ended up going with a strap that uses the split rings, so I'm no longer trying to wrestle them off, but thanks for the info!

Comment: I didn't like the OpTech strap I got, so I switched to a BlackRapid. Once again, I didn't need the strap rings, so I pushed down on the plastic clip and it came right off. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If *"push them HARD towards the on-camera mounting post"* reads like alien language to you, here's a Youtube video showing how to remove the rings.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lRqfZU7Gzg